# Zooming on UICollectionView - locationInView returning strange values

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a zooming effect on a UICollectionView. In order to get the desired effect, I want to do two things:

1. Scale the layout effectively
2. Ensure that the the scaling 'stretches out' from whatever pt sits btwn the two fingers doing the pinching.

The first part is straight forward, now I am moving on to the second.

My strategy is to find the proportional distance from the edge of the collectionView's content to the center of the pinch when the gesture begins, and then ensure that the 'proportional point' (the real value will change based on the scale) remains aligned with the center of the pinch as the touch locations change.

Anyway, the code that does that is this (scaling code not included)

```
CGPoint pinchCenter = [pincher locationInView:self.collectionView];
CGFloat ContentXToAlignWithPinch = self.collectionView.contentSize.width * proportionalXInContent;
CGFloat contentOffsetX = ContentXToAlignWithPinch - pinchCenter.x;    
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(contentOffsetX, 0) animated:NO];
NSLog(@"pinchCenter.x is %", pinchCenter.x);
```

But when I log out that pinchCenter.x i get this:

```
2013-05-10 11:42:08.015 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 1548.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.036 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 203.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.041 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 1560.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.062 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 204.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.083 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 1570.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.102 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 212.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.120 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 1588.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.137 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 216.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.156 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 1593.000000
2013-05-10 11:42:08.175 DMMS[20189:907] pinchCenter.x is 218.000000
```

Why is this pinchCenter.x jumping around like that? Am i incorrect in my assumption that locationInView on a uipinch gesture recognizer gives the midpt of the pinch?

Any help greatly appreciated